# Changing words in a file appending numbers

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, awk

I have a file that has the following form:

```
xcart 1.0 1.0 1.0
1.5 1.5 1.5
3.1 2.0 0.0
xcart 1.0 1.0 1.0
1.5 1.5 1.5
3.1 2.0 0.0
xcart 1.0 1.0 1.0
1.5 1.5 1.5
3.1 2.0 0.0
.............
```

That is, every three lines there is a line which starts with 'xcart'. The values of the numbers don't matter for this question.

I'd like to change every occurrence of 'xcart' for 'xcart1', 'xcart2', 'xcart3' and so on. Let's suppose that I have 120 occurrences of 'xcart'.

So, the final form of my file would be:

```
xcart1 1.0 1.0 1.0
1.5 1.5 1.5
3.1 2.0 0.0
xcart2 1.0 1.0 1.0
1.5 1.5 1.5
3.1 2.0 0.0
xcart3 1.0 1.0 1.0
1.5 1.5 1.5
3.1 2.0 0.0
.............
.............
xcart120 1.0 1.0 1.0
1.5 1.5 1.5 
3.1 2.0 0.0
```

Is there an easy way to do such a thing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check the link for similar problem: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117106/replace-string-with-sequential-index

Answer (score 1):

awk is happy to do this kind of job:

```
awk '$1=="xcart"{$1=$1"" ++i}7' file
```

with your example:

```
kent$  awk '$1=="xcart"{$1=$1"" ++i}7' f
xcart1 1.0 1.0 1.0
1.5 1.5 1.5
3.1 2.0 0.0
xcart2 1.0 1.0 1.0
1.5 1.5 1.5
3.1 2.0 0.0
xcart3 1.0 1.0 1.0
1.5 1.5 1.5
3.1 2.0 0.0
```

Comment: reason for `""` in the assignment ?

Comment: @123 you can remove it and test again, you will see.

Comment: Is that a bug, wouldn't expect it to behave that way ?

Comment: @123 ,no IMO, it is not bug. `a++b` will be `a++  then b` the `""` just let awk know I want to have `a then ++b`, maybe `a (++b)` is better.

Comment: Yes but using `i++ a` gives the (imo) correct result, the `++` should negate any association between the strings in an airthmetic context, as `++` cannot be used as an operator (or isn't defined as one) for arithmetic between two strings.

Comment: @123 in awk, AFAIK, if you have a string `a="foo"`, you can do `a++`, In this example, it is same `0++`, if you `print a` after `a++`, it would be `1`. so: `a++b` will do `a++` first, then concatenate `b` as string.

Comment: I personally think the space between the variable and `++` should indicate which variable is being acted on, but yeah that makes sense.

Comment: @123 it is easy to test, do this : `awk 'BEGIN{a=100;b=999;x=a     ++    b;print x}'`

Comment: I wasn't saying it doesn't behave that way, i was saying i'm not sure that it should.

Comment: @Kent certainly by no means required, but `awk` is one of those commands I'd like to know more about and I find the best learning tools are specific use cases. Would you care to add a section explaining what is happening in this example? It would be greatly appreciated by me and I would expect others.